# Rollback transaction multiple query

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, rollback

I have a store procedure like below:

```
DECLARE @FinalQuery varchar(max), @TableName varchar(200)
DECLARE ListTable CURSOR FOR SELECT....
DECLARE @isError bit=0
OPEN ListTable 
FETCH NEXT FROM ListTable INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    //Some code to generate @FinalQuery to merge data into table @TableName
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC(@FinalQuery)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        Set @IsError = 1
        //Some code to write error to log file.
    END CATCH
    FETCH NEXT FROM ListTable INTO @TableName
END
CLOSE ListTable 
DEALLOCATE ListTable
```

Now, I want to add transaction and rollback to my store procedure. I want all dynamic @FinalQuery query to be executed, and finally, when it finish, if any error exists ( @IsError=1) then rollback everything. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 BEGIN TRAN
 BEGIN TRY
   EXEC(@FinalQuery)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    Set @IsError = 1
    //Some code to write error to log file.
ROLLBACK
END CATCH
COMMIT
```

Comment: I got this error: The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction.

Comment: Different error: The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

Comment: Last try, if not then I have no idea how to help :)

Comment: The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction again. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1170215-146-1.aspx

Check this link maybe will be somehow helpful

Answer (score 0):

As you want all the changes to be rolled back in the event of an error, have you tried moving the transaction out of the loop?

```
OPEN ListTable 
FETCH NEXT FROM ListTable INTO @TableName
BEGIN TRY
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        //Some code to generate @FinalQuery to merge data into table @TableName
        EXEC(@FinalQuery)
        FETCH NEXT FROM ListTable INTO @TableName
    END
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    Set @IsError = 1
    //Some code to write error to log file.
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
CLOSE ListTable 
DEALLOCATE ListTable
```